# Google Compute Engine Tesla K80 has additional HtoD an DtoH ops and a way lower GPU Utilization then desktop GTX 1080

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Context:**
I have created a Hierarchical RNN in tensorflow on my desktop computer (`tensorflow-gpu 1.2`, `cuda v 8.0.44`, `GPU GTX 1080`), and then decided to scale training on Google Cloud Platform (Compute Engine) with a quite pure setup (2x `Tesla K80`, `nvidia-docker` with `gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3` image, `cuda v 8.0.61`). 
The code for both models is identical.

**Problem:**
The Volatile GPU Util. is dramatically different in both cases:

- GPU GTX 1080: ≈85-90%
- Tesla K80: ≈40%

What really interests me is that Timeline traces are very different - on GTX 1080 there are no `MEMCPYHtoD` or `MEMCPYDtoH` ops, while they are present on GCP CE instance, though setups are approximately same.

[Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419116/yaroslav-bulatov) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319786/low-gpu-usage-performance-with-tensorflow-rnns#comment71793774_42319786) that

> HtoD in timeline suggests some GPU ops don't have native GPU implementations.

, but then why there are no HtoDs on the desktop?

I wonder what is special about using/scaling tensorflow models on GCE?

**Timeline GTX 1080** (Desktop)

[image: GTX 1080]

**Timeline Tesla K80** (GCE)

[image: Tesla K80]

Comment: tensorflow-gpu uses the cudnn and cublas libraries to accelerate various GPU operations.  It's entirely possible that these libraries have dramatically different code paths on different GPU types, for what is otherwise the same operation (e.g. a matrix-matrix multiply)  CPU matters here as well.  If CPU is faster/slower, then the work issuance rate to the GPU may be affected (since, at some level, the CPU is issuing work to the GPU).  If the work is issued at a slower rate to the GPU, the apparent measured utilization may go down.

Comment: It's possible the HtoD and DtoH could be because GCE doesn't support P2P needed for the K80.

Comment: my read of the question suggests that in each case the tensorflow work is being run on a single GPU device, for both the 1080 case and the K80 case. If that is the case, P2P would not enter the picture.  The GCE K80 profile trace above only shows a `gpu:0` device in use.

Comment: Yes, indeed, in this example only one K80 is used, but the situation is the same if I use 2 GPUs. My main question is why there are even HtoD and DtoH on GCE in the first place. Why would GPU need to do these extra memcpy operations when it can easily bypass them in a desktop setting. It obviously adds additional overhead and time consumption.

Comment: Answering this would involve detailed performance analysis of your code,  basically the entire tensorflow codebase and potentially CUDNN and CUBLAS add well. That is a gigantic undertaking for s [SO] question

Comment: The Pascal-generation GTX 1080 supports on-demand paging, while Kepler K80 doesn't. This is a _possible_ explanation why you might not see any explicit memcpys on the timeline for the GTX 1080 (though I don't know the codebase). As Robert said, the codepaths for varying architectures might be very different.

Comment: Maybe a different model option, or different TensorFlow versions? Hard to say more without more details about the model.